# Missing header files on Mac 10.6.8 stop compilation (SNAP software installation)

Tags: c++, macos, unix, header, include

I'm trying to install [Stanford Network Analysis Project](http://snap.stanford.edu/).

I work on MacOS 10.6.8. Yesterday I've downloaded the latest compatible version of Xcode (3.1.4) in order to get the GCC package with a C++ compiler.

When I run the "make" command in my Unix Terminal I get hundreds line of errors.

The first one is about a missing file named "poll.h".

```
make -C snap-core 
g++ -c -std=c++98 -Wall  -O3 -I/Xcode3.1.4/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/sys -I/Xcode3.1.4/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers Snap.cpp -I../glib-core
In file included from Snap.h:8,
                 from Snap.cpp:4:
../glib-core/base.h:68:24: error: sys/poll.h: No such file or directory
../glib-core/base.h:75:21: error: netdb.h: No such file or directory
../glib-core/base.h:76:25: error: arpa/inet.h: No such file or directory
```

I've searched on my hard drive where this "poll.h" file was. I can't find it. I can't find netdb.h or inet.h and a few others either.

These files are not the first ones to be included. I'm saying this to make clear that some files are found but some others are missing. This is what actually happen before I encouter the error:

```
  #include <stdint.h>
  #include <stdarg.h>
  #include <errno.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #include <dirent.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <signal.h>
  #include <sys/poll.h>
```

As several files are missing I believe I'm missing something big in this issue. Nonethelless I've found out a way to download "poll.h" [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/sys/poll.h). I don't feel comfortable using it... How can I be sure it's the proper file ? What about the other missing files ?

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot. Nicolas.

Comment: Xcode 3.1.4?  That's about 3-4 years old.  The latest version is 4.5.2, try that instead.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: 4.5.2 won't run on Mac OS X 10.6. 3.6.2 is the latest version that will run on Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: Indeed, this is why I'm running such an old version. 
To be accurate I could have downloaded the version 3.2.6 (4,14Gb) or 3.2.5 (3,5Gb) but my connection is really slow and I don't if I'll manage to get the DMG file at all.

Comment: dreamlax, I think you mean Xcode 3.2.6. There is also a version of Xcode 4.2 that runs on 10.6 but it is not generally available for free, as 3.2.6 is.

Comment: @NedDeily: Whoops yes I meant 3.2.6, and yes I meant it's the latest "free" version of Xcode for 10.6.

Comment: Is there anyway to check if the missing headers may be included in Xcode 3.2.6 or Xcode 3.2.5 ? I'm having a look on http://www.opensource.apple.com/ but I don't really know how to search .

Comment: @NicolasRichard: I have 3.2.6 and those headers are present in `/<XcodeDir>/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include`.

Comment: @dreamlax Thanks I'm currently trying to download Xcode 3.2.5. 7 hours to go.

Comment: After a few hours of download I managed to put my hands on Xcode 4.2. This simply solved the problem.